# Thymeleaf + Spring Boot: webcontext object 'session' is not working properly

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is my controller,

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {
    @GetMapping(value="/categories")
    public String searchCategory(Map<String, Object> model, HttpSession session) {
        Category filter = (Category) session.getAttribute("filter");
        if(filter == null) {
            filter = new Category();
            session.setAttribute("filter", filter);
        }

        ...

        return "category-list";
    }   
}
```

I stored an object into session, and would display it on the UI with below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
            ...
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" th:field="${session.filter.name}" placeholder="name"/>
            ...
</body>
```

**But I ended up with below error message, it seems to me Thymeleaf treated 'session' as an normal object in the request, intead of a predefined Webcontext object**

```
2016-10-27 10:34:53.655 ERROR 5844 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() fo
r servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/smartact] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested except
ion is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path
 resource [templates/datamaster/category-list.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'session' available as requ
est attribute**
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.BUILD-SN
APSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:307) ~[thymeleaf-spri
ng4-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:258) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.0.RELEASE.ja
r:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.0.RELEASE.ja
r:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.jav
a:173) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74
) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
```

Any comments is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: use `th:text="${session.filter.name}"`

Comment: That is what `th:field` does. It refers to a field of a specified object (normally the command object). You probably want to use `th:text` instead.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. I'd like to put 'filter' as a command object for Query-by-Example, and I want the searching criteria to being in Session so that the searching criteria would last between different requests. th:text can't keep the user input. Am I right? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As Prasanna Kumar already stated, use `th:text="${filter.name}"` (note that `filter` is a name of attribute). However, there's one more important thing: Do NOT fill your session unnecessary! In worst case, set it as a Spring's session attribute. Usually, you'll use request attributes:

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {
    @GetMapping(value="/categories")
    public String searchCategory(@ModelAttribute("filter") Category filter, Model model) {
        filter = new Category();
        model.addAttribute("filter", filter);

        ...

        return "category-list";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Branislav, please refer my reply above.